# How to remove the URL from the printing page?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, internet-explorer, css

Recent a user report when user printing some page, the page all URL will display on the paper(NOT are HEADER AND FOOTER), I know the google chrome f12>rendering>emulate> screen can  force  print out  What You See Is What You Get but the office user only have are limited computer knowledge, How can I use GPO or any tools can disable it or force google chrome/IE print WYSIWYG ?

For Example:

> Search(..../search)
>
> Submit(../submit.php)       Logout(.../logout.php)